# Phone call in react native

Tags: react-native, phone-call

I want to make a phone call in React Native, I am a beginner on react native so I came across this question which looks like mine => [How to make phone call in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545064/how-to-make-phone-call-in-react-native/57056709)

So, this is a part of my code but it's not working, when I click on the icon, nothing is happening and I have no error on my terminal, it's very weird. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Avatar } from "react-native-elements";
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

export const makeCall = () => {

    let phoneNumber = '';

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        phoneNumber = 'tel:${0123456789}';
    } else {
        phoneNumber = 'telprompt:${0123456789}';
    }

    Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
};

const Contacts = () => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.column}>
       <Avatar
         size={65}
         rounded
         overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
         icon={{ name: 'phone', color: '#113D78', type: 'font-awesome' }}
         onPress={() => makeCall}
         style={{
           width: 65,
           height: 65,
           borderRadius: 50,
           borderWidth: 2,
           borderColor: '#113D78',
         }}
     />
     <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Phone</Text>
   </View>
);
```

}

export default Contacts;

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not using the backticks for your phoneNumber string if you have a phoneNumber variable. Right now you are hardcoding the numbers so just use `tel:12345678` without the curly brackets and dollar sign. Also, `tel:${number}` should work on both platforms if you use newer react-native versions.
And keep in mind that opening calls is not supported on the iOS simulator, so you have to test on a real device or on android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I put on backticks and tested on my phone and it worked fine, but I use tel:+3312345678! I thought it worked on emulator too

Answer (score 1):

your issue is here. in this function

```
export const makeCall = () => {

    let phoneNumber = '';

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        phoneNumber = 'tel:${0123456789}';   // Error in this line
    } else {
        phoneNumber = 'telprompt:${0123456789}';
    }

    Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
};
```

it should be like this

```
export const makeCall = () => {

    let phoneNumber = '';

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        phoneNumber = `tel:${0123456789}`;
    } else {
        phoneNumber = `telprompt:${0123456789}`;
    }

    Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this line of code should work on both platforms as you replace `phoneNumber` by the number you want to call.

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native'
Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Template Literal` you used in your code but it is not in right way. You used `'...'` single quote instead of ``` backtick (``) ```.

They were called `template strings` in prior editions of the `ECMAScript 2015` specification.

`Template literals` are supported by `Chrome 41`, `Firefox 34`, and `Edge 12` and above, but not supported by `Internet Explorer`.

You can explore more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) about this.

However, I used your code in my app and checked in `emulator`. It works right now.

You can use only `string` with single quote `'...'` and without `&{...}` as like bellow:

```
let phoneNumber = '';

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        phoneNumber = 'tel:0123456789';
    } else {
        phoneNumber = 'telprompt:0123456789';
    }

    Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
```

Or you have to use ``` backtick (``) ``` if you use `${...}` because it means that you are using a `variable` or a `number` in a `template string` as like below:

```
let phoneNumber = ``;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        phoneNumber = `tel:${0123456789}`;
    } else {
        phoneNumber = `telprompt:${0123456789}`;
    }

    Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
```

Hope you understood the use case as well.