# I want to navigate to default phone app on android on clicking phone_call image how to do that using react native?

Tags: android, react-native

My first page which contain Image on click of that image android default dial pad page will open .Use API to open phone Dialpadp.

Comment: Check this solution. [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288735/13632102)

`onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('tel:123456');}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native'

let phoneNumber = '+911234567890'
    
Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`)
```

With the help of the Linking function, you can directly get the number on the dial-pad.